# Is cosmetic surgery allowed for a Muslim women to please her husband?

Tags: halal-haram, medical, human-body

I am a Muslim woman and realise that I have a duty to my husband to please him and do what I need to do to keep us together. Lately however I feel the attraction between us has not been the way it used to be and I feel that he will start to look elsewhere.

I know the flaws I have that are aesthetic and I want to know if changing them cosmetically through surgery for the sake of keeping my husband interested is haram. I have thought about many other options such as make up, but he hates it when I wear it so I'd rather do something that doesn't require me to wear it. I am sure if I undergo the change he will be more visually pleased.

Comment: I would suggest you to read this fatwa http://islamqa.info/en/84849 and let your husband read it, it's clearly a different matter, but surgery is a grief intervention you should think well about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of surgeries:

- To make a person look better: Forbidden by majority of scholars even if it is requested by the Husband
- To correct something that isn't natural, like a deformity or disfigurement. That is allowed for any person

[Source](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/55971)

Ask yourself which part you are from and decide on your own. My personal opinion, why do you have to look good for him, it goes both ways, he also needs to look good for you. If he doesn't like you for who you are you are better of without him.